# Python's time.sleep() function freezes Postgres DB time in Django tests

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sleep, pytest-django

I need to make a pause in my Django project's test (I use pytest-django) and time.sleep() kind of works but with a strange side effect. It pauses the execution of the code as expected but it also stops Postgresql's "in-DB clock" that is not desired. Here is an example:

```python
from pytest import mark, fixture, raises
from django.db import connection
from django.utils import timezone
import sys, datetime as dt

@mark.django_db
def test_db_time ():
    print('Code time before:', timezone.now(), file = sys.stderr)
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT NOW()")
        print('DB NOW() before:',
              t_before := cursor.fetchone()[0],
              file = sys.stderr)

    sleep(1.56)

    print('Code time after:', timezone.now(), file = sys.stderr)
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT NOW()")
        print('DB NOW() after:',
              t_after := cursor.fetchone()[0],
              file = sys.stderr)

    assert t_before != t_after, 'I need a nap!'
```

When run this test with pytest, I get the next output:

```
========================================= test session starts =========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.1, pytest-7.4.0, pluggy-1.0.0
django: settings: pms.settings (from ini)
rootdir: /home/nikita/files/projects/pms/dev
configfile: pyproject.toml
plugins: django-4.5.2
collected 1 item                                                                                      

sis/tests/db/triggers/test_answer.py F                                                          [100%]

============================================== FAILURES ===============================================
____________________________________________ test_db_time _____________________________________________

    def test_db_time ():
        print('Code time before:', timezone.now(), file = sys.stderr)
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT NOW()")
            print('DB NOW() before:',
                  t_before := cursor.fetchone()[0],
                  file = sys.stderr)
    
        sleep(1.56)
    
        print('Code time after:', timezone.now(), file = sys.stderr)
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT NOW()")
            print('DB NOW() after:',
                  t_after := cursor.fetchone()[0],
                  file = sys.stderr)
    
>       assert t_before != t_after, 'I need a nap!'
E       AssertionError: I need a nap!
E       assert datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 7, 15, 14, 14, 414343, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc) != datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 7, 15, 14, 14, 414343, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

sis/tests/db/triggers/test_answer.py:114: AssertionError
---------------------------------------- Captured stderr call -----------------------------------------
Code time before: 2023-09-07 15:14:14.414191+00:00
DB NOW() before: 2023-09-07 15:14:14.414343+00:00
Code time after: 2023-09-07 15:14:15.976308+00:00
DB NOW() after: 2023-09-07 15:14:14.414343+00:00
======================================= short test summary info =======================================
FAILED sis/tests/db/triggers/test_answer.py::test_db_time - AssertionError: I need a nap!
========================================== 1 failed in 3.05s ==========================================
```

Why does it happen and how to make "DB clock" work properly? I thought NOW() must take time from the system but system time is running properly during the time.sleep pause.

Comment: Are you sure this is not just the clock not updating very fast. What if you sleep 20 seconds?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yep, 20 seconds don't change anything. timezone.now() times are different by ~20 sec while DB NOW() is "frozen"

Comment: Read [Current date/time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT): *...now() is a traditional PostgreSQL equivalent to transaction_timestamp().* which means it is pegged to the start of the transaction. Pretty sure you want `clock_timestamp()`. Read the docs at the link for more information.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver That's it, thanks! `clock_timestamp()` is what I'm looking for. It works exactly as expected in this context